# Low Level Setting the System Cursor to Custom in .Net Office Interop

Tags: c#, winapi, office-interop, low-level

I am writing a .Net WPF Application that allows other programs to write to it. One of the features the designers want to implement is a custom cursor that is used in the third party programs to replace the Text-Editor "I-Beam" one.

The first third party program I have been messing with is MS Word 2013, using .Net's Office Interop stuff. I have a Global C# DLL in my program's application domain that holds the cursor resource.

Interop doesn't allow you to assign custom cursors (although it does allow you to switch the cursor). So after a lot of digging, I attempted some low level messing around.

In the Interop Addin, I added this class:

```
public static class CursorHook

{


    private static IntPtr programCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static IntPtr systemCursor = LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, OCR_IBEAM);

    public static void Init()
    {
        programCursor = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(resourceCursor.marker_cursor2.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(resourceCursor.marker_cursor2, 0, programCursor, resourceCursor.marker_cursor2.Length);
    }

    public static void Start()
    {



        SetSystemCursor(programCursor, OCR_IBEAM);

    }
    public static void Stop()
    {
        SetSystemCursor(systemCursor, OCR_IBEAM);


    }

    public static void Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(programCursor);
    }

    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;





    private const int OCR_IBEAM = 32513;





    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hCursor, uint id);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int id);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetCursor(IntPtr hCursor);


}
```

In my addin class, I do this:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    //Stuff
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CursorHook.Init();
        CursorHook.Start();

        this.Application.WindowDeactivate += new WordInterop.ApplicationEvents4_WindowDeactivateEventHandler(Deactivated);
        this.Application.WindowActivate += new WordInterop.ApplicationEvents4_WindowActivateEventHandler(Activated);
        //Stuff
    }


    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CursorHook.Stop();
        CursorHook.Dispose(); 
    }

    //stuff

     private void Activated(WordInterop.Document Doc, WordInterop.Window Wn) { CursorHook.Start(); }
    private void Deactivated(WordInterop.Document Doc, WordInterop.Window Wn) { CursorHook.Stop(); }

    //stuff

}
```

Yet, the cursor doesn't change (even though the code is called). What am I missing?

BTW, I understand the bigger picture about how a static class may not be the best use of resources. But right now, I am just trying to get the cursor to do what I want it to, I will work on elegance after this is accomplished.

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*

I have modified the code to look like this:

```
public static class CursorHook

{


    private static IntPtr ptr_IBeam = IntPtr.Zero;


    private static IntPtr programCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static IntPtr systemCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static Cursor ProgramCursor = null;


    public static void Init()
    {


        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(resourceCursor.marker_cursor2))
        {
            ProgramCursor = new Cursor(ms);
        }
        programCursor = ProgramCursor.Handle;
        systemCursor = Cursors.IBeam.CopyHandle();

    }

    public static void Start()
    {

         SetSystemCursor(programCursor, UNS_OCR_IBEAM);

    }


    public static void Stop()
    {

            SetSystemCursor(systemCursor, UNS_OCR_IBEAM);         


    }

    public static void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private const int OCR_IBEAM = 32513;
    private const uint UNS_OCR_IBEAM = OCR_IBEAM;
    private static IntPtr PTR_OCR_IBEAM = new IntPtr(OCR_IBEAM);





    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hCursor, uint id);




}
```

It is now much simpler all around, thanks largely to HansPassant's comment below. It actually somewhat works, now, too!

Yet, there are still two bugs.

1) The icon is not in color. I know this is an issue with custom icons and there are workarounds, so I will research that myself.

**What has me stuck**:
2) The icon will turn to my custom icon on opening Word, and will change back to the default one when clicking outside of Word. But then it will refuse to change back to my icon after this. SetSystemCursor() will return false each time I "activate" MS Word. Why?

Comment: It's safe to assume that the target window handles the [WM_SETCURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382.aspx), setting its own cursor as it sees fit, thus undoing your naïve attempt to change the cursor shape.

Comment: Except I am attempting to change the SYSTEM cursor so it doesn't matter what the target window does.

Comment: That assumes that the target window is using the SYSTEM cursor.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair point. It is MS Word, though. When I change the system cursor through Control Panel to my custom cursor, MS Word uses it.

Comment: Error checking is not optional.  SetSystemCursor can return *false*, you'll never know it.  Second argument of LoadCursor is IntPtr, not int. Marshal.AllocHGlobal() + Copy() is not correct, use the Icon.Handle property instead.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you very much for your constructive advice. I'm about to test it. 

I got my loadcursor() types from here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.loadcursor

Interesting how the VB code reflects what you said, and the C# code says otherwise.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. You're writing a program, but then you're writing an addin for Word? And changing the system cursor to override an application cursor is the wrong solution: it's a global solution to a local problem. This is more critical than anything about whether a static class is good practice or not (which is highly subjective).

Comment: @andlabs This is indeed a problem. However, I cannot see another way to change Word's IBeam cursor to my custom one as the Interop API itself only allows you to manipulate the cursor through Enums to the System cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code. It works but the cursor is not in color. As colored cursors are a known headache in Windows, it's a different problem. Big thanks to Hans Passant

```
public static class CursorHook

{




    private static IntPtr programCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static IntPtr systemCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static Cursor ProgramCursor = null;

    private static Cursor DefaultCursor = null;


    public static void Init()
    {


        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(resourceCursor.marker_cursor2))
        {
            ProgramCursor = new Cursor(ms);
        }
        DefaultCursor = new Cursor(Cursors.IBeam.CopyHandle());



    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        //as the GC has likely invalidated the IntPtr, each time you have to assign it anew
        programCursor = ProgramCursor.CopyHandle();
         SetSystemCursor(programCursor, UNS_OCR_IBEAM);

    }


    public static void Stop()
    {
        //as the GC has likely invalidated the IntPtr, each time you have to assign it anew
        systemCursor = DefaultCursor.CopyHandle();
        SetSystemCursor(systemCursor, UNS_OCR_IBEAM);         


    }

    public static void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private const int OCR_IBEAM = 32513;
    private const uint UNS_OCR_IBEAM = OCR_IBEAM;
    private static IntPtr PTR_OCR_IBEAM = new IntPtr(OCR_IBEAM);





    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hCursor, uint id);




}
```